# Find and extract a number from a file

Tags: regex, bash, macos, cocoapods, podfile

So I want to create script to update a version number.

The file contents look like this.
I struggle to extract the number from the file.
I want to extract and parse the number "58"
The other numbers might also change.
The file contents look like this.:

```rb
# Some more lines above
    pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '0.2.58'
# More lines below
```

My approach was to use `grep -o Alamofire.git.*[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]+ ../Podfile`

But this doesn't work.
Is there any easy solution to this?

Comment: the line you refer seems to be extracted from a `Podfile`, I think your question should reference that since the solution might be some command that gets the version number by actually evaluating the ruby file itself. By looking briefly, seems like [this plugin](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods-podfile_info) may help you, but I'm not at all a cocoapod user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `ggrep`

```
ggrep -oP 'Alamofire\.git.*[0-9]\.[0-9]\.\K[0-9]+' ../Podfile
```

Output

```
58
```

---

Another option with `awk` and a bit more specific match setting the `.` and `'` as a field separator:

```
awk -F"[.']" '
match ($0, /Alamofire\.git.*\047[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\047$/) {
  print $(NF-1)
}' file
```

Or with `gnu-awk` and a capture group:

```
gawk 'match($0, /Alamofire\.git.*[0-9]\.[0-9]\.([0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]}' ../Podfile
```

Comment: Ah so I need to install GNU grep using brew ggrep?

Comment: @Tbi You might do that if it is an option. I have added an awk and gnu awk alternative as well.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples and **in any** `awk` **version** please try following
`awk` code. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/60PGql/1) for used regex (`^[[:space:]]+pod \047Alamofire\047, :git => \047https?:\/\/github\.com\/.*\/Alamofire\.git\047, :tag => \047([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+\047`) to get needed values by OP.

```
awk '
match($0,/^[[:space:]]+pod \047Alamofire\047, :git => \047https?:\/\/github\.com\/.*\/Alamofire\.git\047, :tag => \047([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+\047/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/.*\.|\047$/,"",val)
  print val
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^[[:space:]]+pod   ##From starting of value matching space(s) followed by string pod followed by a space.
\047Alamofire\047, ##Matching ' followed by Alamofire followed by ' and comma here.
:git => \047https? ##Matching :git space => followed by ' http and keeping s optional(to match http also).
:\/\/github\.com\/ ##Matching colon // github.com followed by a / here.
.*\/Alamofire\.git ##Matching everything till / followed by Alamofire followed by .git here.
\047, :tag => \047 ##Matching ', followed by space :tag followed by space => followed by space and ' here.
([0-9]+\.)+        ##Matching digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by dot and this whole group 1 or more times.
[0-9]+\047         ##Matching 1 or more digits followed by a ' here.
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Grep:

```
grep -o -P 'Alamofire.*:tag.*\.\K\d+' file
```

Sed:

```
sed -nE 's/.*Alamofire.*\.([[:digit:]]*).*/\1/p' file
```

Awk:

```
awk -F. '/Alamofire/{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"", $NF); print $NF}' file
```

POSIX grep native on MacOS you can use a pipe:

```
grep 'Alamofire' file | tr -d [\'\"] | rev | cut -d'.' -f 1 | rev
```